# How to create dynamic metric

Tags: postgresql, metrics, sematic

Hi we are trying to create dynamic metrics through the UI and we are unable to figure out proper way to do it we have made a ui which look like the screenshot below. What we are trying to achieve is when a user selects the particular dataset and based on selecting columns and rows we are able to construct a metrics on runtime and show it to the user.

[image]

Can please someone guide us on this what could be proper way or tools to achieve this.